# Ciclo de Vida de uma Activity. Duvidas

Tags: android

Os metodos que compõem o ciclo de vida de uma activity (onCreate, onStart, onResume, onPause, onStop e onDestroy), excetuando o metodo onCreate que ja é inserido no inicio da aplicação, os outros sao chamados automaticamente pela aplicação? Ou o desenvolvedor, utilizando boas práticas, deve utiliza-los nos seus aplicativos?

Comment: São executados automaticamente, você pode consultar mais informações [aqui](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/activity-lifecycle.html)

Comment: Como o Denis falou, todos os métodos do ciclo de vida de uma activity são executados automaticamente, no entanto você pode sobrescrever esses métodos. Você pode, por exemplo, chamar métodos no onResume da sua aplicação entre outras coisas que você achar necessário no seu app.

Answer (score 0):

Os métodos relacionados ao ciclo de vida de uma Activity são chamados automaticamente, mesmo que não os veja explicitamente em seu código eles existem, esse é o esqueleto básico de uma atividade:

```
public class ExampleActivity extends Activity {
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        // The activity is being created.
    }
    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        // The activity is about to become visible.
    }
    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        // The activity has become visible (it is now "resumed").
    }
    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        // Another activity is taking focus (this activity is about to be "paused").
    }
    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        // The activity is no longer visible (it is now "stopped")
    }
    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        // The activity is about to be destroyed.
    }
}
```

Lembrando que seu código deve **SEMPRE** estar depois da implementação de chamada da superclasse.

Dependendo da aplicação criada deve-se editar essas métodos, é uma boa prática, a conexão com o banco ser fechada quando a aplicação entrarem `onPause()` e reaberta em `onResume()` para evitar gastos de recursos, isso ocorre, por exemplo, quando alguém recebe uma chamada durante o uso da aplicação, e a mesma acaba usando recursos desnecessariamente, prejudicando a experiencia do usuário